# PUT method throws BadMethodCallException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm learning Laravel from Lacast and i'm trying to create a CRUD application.I've implemented the `index,show,create`  and `store` correctly,but with the `edit` form when i try to submit data it's throwing `BadMethodCallException`.
Here are my routes

```
Route::get('/projects','ProjectsController@index');
Route::get('/projects/{id}','ProjectsController@show')->where('id','[0-9]+');


Route::get('/create','ProjectsController@create');
Route::post('/projects','ProjectsController@store');

Route::get('/projects/{id}/edit','ProjectsController@edit')->where('id','[0-9]+');
Route::put('/projects/{id}','ProjectsController@update')->where('id','[0-9]+');

Route::delete('/projects/{id}','ProjectsController@destroy');
```

Here is the `edit` form:

```
@extends('template');
@section('content')
    <h2>Create new project</h2>
<p>/projects/{{ $project->id }}</p>    
<form method="POST" action="/projects/{{ $project->id }}">
        {{ method_field('PUT') }}
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div>
            <input value="{{ $project->title }}" type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Project title">
        </div>
        <div>
            <textarea  name="description" placeholder="Enter the project description">{{ $project->description }}</textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Update project</button>
        </div>
    </form>
@endsection
```

The controller code:

```
 public function edit($id){
        $project= Project::find($id);
        return view('projects.edit',compact('project'));
    }

    public function update($id){
        $project= Project::find($id);
        $project->title=request('title');
        $project->description('description');
        $project->save();
        return redirect('/projects');
    }
```

The `edit form` displays as expected with data coming from the database,after submit i get the following error page:
[image]

With the example of the instructor the code has worked perfectly,and before using the `PUT` either on my form and in my controller i used `PATCH` like the instructor but always the same result.

Here is the instructor video link: [Faking PATCH and DELETE Requests](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018/episodes/12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty straightforward.

```
public function update($id){
    $project= Project::find($id);
    $project->title=request('title');
    $project->description('description'); // You don't have a method description()
    $project->save();
    return redirect('/projects');
}
```

This is what you probably meant to do:

```
public function update($id)
{
    $project= Project::find($id);

    $project->title = request('title');
    $project->description = request('description');
    $project->save();

    return redirect('/projects');
}
```